# Return new identity value from table adapter Insert command

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, insert, identity

I have an `insert` statement in a table adapter, but it keeps returning 1, instead of the id of the newly inserted row. Why?

```
Dim TA As New pTableAdapters.householdsTableAdapter
lblResult.Text = TA.Insert(New Guid("32dd20eb-1691-457b-9ff5-fc41d687e578"), Trim(Title), 0, "add", "addr2", _
            "4544", "london", "ld", 0, "", Date.Now)
```

The insert statement in the table adapter:

```
INSERT INTO households (userid, title, side, address, address2, zipcode, city, state, country, notes, createdate) VALUES (@userid,@title,@side,@address,@address2,@zipcode,@city,@state,@country,@notes,@createdate);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/10/31/returnidentityvaluequery.aspx

> ... There's one last important piece: select the new query in the DataSet Designer and change the ExecuteMode property from NonQuery to Scalar. ...

NonQuery will return the affected row count (hence why you always get a 1), while Scalar mode returns the selected value itself.

Comment: I cant find the `ExectuteMode` on the InsertCommand property of the tableadapter...where would I find it?

Comment: Seems that your suggestion does not work for he regular Insert commands....I had to add my own custom Insert statement and then it works.